# XNA model texture from file

Tags: xna, c#, textures

Is there any way to have the texture of a model loaded from a Png ?

I have a simple prism to test it on, but i just want to be able to edit an image and have the model's texture change.

Thanks!

Comment: [Start here](http://efron-xna.blogspot.com/2006/11/rendering-textured-cube.html) and extrapolate your solution.

Comment: Crap, I once wrote the perfect tutorial on this for you but it was on Ziggyware which unfortunately went down and I don't have a backup :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a png as a texture. First you have to add it to the game project content :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282477(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx

And then you call Load method of ContentManager :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/bb197848(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx

You can access the ContentManager through the Content properties of Game class :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.content(v=XNAGameStudio.40).aspx

Comment: But how can i actually render it onto the model? Also how can i know what configuration the texture should be in to fit onto the model?

Comment: To render a texture on a model, it had to have uv coordinate. Does your model comes from a graphics software? The easiest solution to do this is to use a graphics software such as 3DS Max, Maya or Blender. You will draw a model and then apply a texture to it. Then these software will give you a file containing all informations about your model. After you just have to add it to your project and load it.

Comment: It was done in Sketchup as a 2 second throw together. I guess i'll load it in 3ds or whatever now to check it out.

Comment: By searching google i find these links wich can help you : http://www.jamesewelch.com/2008/03/07/how-to-load-a-google-sketchup-model-into-a-xna-game/ and http://wiki.flightgear.org/Textures_%26_Texture_Maps_in_SketchUp

Comment: Ahh there we go, didn't know that the textures would be stored outside the .x Thanks for the links :)